# Confirmation of Universal and Existential Quantification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im new to the discrete mathematics scene and was wondering if I could confirm some stuff just to make sure i am getting the concepts correctly. All three of these questions deal specifically with quantifiers. so for the questions.

1. ∃ at(King John, Stanford) ∧ smart (king john)
2. ∀ at ( King John, Stanford) ^ smart ( king john)

so if I were to convert these to sentence's would it be:

1. There exists a person at Stanford named king john who is smart
2. Everyone named king john at Standford is smart

Im not really sure if these are correct as my book does not give me any way to check my answers & this is the only way to get my practice in.

and one more question for some reason in my readings it says that

∃x At (x, Standford) ⇒ Smart(x)

(would be true if there is anyone who is not at Stanford)
which I do not really seem to understand

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems correct.
Here are psuedo symbolic logic renderings of your English statements. Notice the needed parentheses.

Exists x with (x at Standford & x named King John & x is smart).

For all x, (x at Standford & x named King John implies x is smart).